# Use SQLite with biicode

Tags: sqlite, biicode

So far I have been able to succesfully use boost, cereal and gtest using biicode but I am having troubles with sqlite. I am trying to use it doing the following:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
```

So I edited my biicode.conf to include those lines, including the alising for the header:

```
[requirements]
    sqlite/sqlite:9
[includes]
    sqlite.h: sqlite/sqlite/sqlite3/sqlite3.h
```

But when I try to call bii cpp:build it does the following

```
WARN: Removing unused reference to "sqlite/sqlite: 9" from myuser/test "requirements"
```

Then I ended up with the expected:

```
database_impl.cpp:(.text+0x516): undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
```

Surprisingly, the compilation succedd even though sqlite3.h is obviously not included but that's maybe because the call to sqlite is from a template function.

I have looked at the [example](http://docs.biicode.com/c++/examples/sqlite.html) but CMakeList.txt does not seem to add any additional includes directories. For example for boost I had to add:

```
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
bii_find_boost(COMPONENTS chrono system filesystem log thread REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(${BII_BLOCK_TARGET} INTERFACE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${BII_BLOCK_TARGET} INTERFACE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

But the two examples I found [here](https://www.biicode.com/examples/examples/sqlite_basic/master/0/CMakeLists.txt) and [here](https://www.biicode.com/examples/examples/sqlite/master/2/CMakeLists.txt) don't seem to add anything to the includes directories, not even a link folder. I suppose sqlite has to be compiled with your sources so how do I make biicode add those files to my projects automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several problems. You just wrote in `[includes]` section `sqlite.h` instead of `sqlite3.h` and you should only write the prefix, `sqlite/sqlite/sqlite3`, later instead of the full dependency name.

Then, you can solve it so:

```
[requirements]
    sqlite/sqlite: 9
[includes]
    sqlite3.h: sqlite/sqlite/sqlite3
```

Or, you could try the SQLite version uploaded into [fenix](https://www.biicode.com/fenix) user:

```
[requirements]
    fenix/sqlite: 0
[includes]
    sqlite3.h: fenix/sqlite
```

Don't worry about a "WARN" message that says biicode is ignoring sqlite3.c file because it's harcoded into the block CMakeLists.txt to catch this file ;)

**Note**: you should write your external `#includes`'s with double quotes instead of `<>`, because the last ones are referred to system headers and biicode could be using some system deps and you don't realize it.

Comment: sqlite/sqlite solution didn't work but using fenix/sqlite solved the issue, thank you!